# Reading and Writing special characters in Python

Tags: python, gzip, special-characters, read-write

**Python ver. 3.11.5 on Windows 10**

I have a directory filled with .gz text archives. To scan these archives, I use the following python code:

```
    with gzip.open(logDir+"\\"+fileName, mode="rb") as archive:
        for filename in archive:
            print(filename.decode().strip())
```

All used to work, however, the new system adds lines similar to this:

`:§f Press [§bJ§f]`

Python gives me this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Python\ConvertLog.py", line 16, in readZIP print(filename.decode().strip())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa7 in position 49: invalid start byte
```

Anyone know a way of dealing with strange characters that pop up? I can't just ignore the line. This happens to be one of the few lines I need to strip out and write to a condensed report.

I tried other modes, besides "rb". I really have no idea what else to try.

Comment: Have you tried `print(filename)`, without the `.decode().strip()`?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did that first. I honestly dont understand why, but without that, it just prints numbers. Billions of numbers.

Comment: _without that, it just prints numbers_ That's because it isn't a filename; it's the **content** of the uncompressed file.  Why did you think it would be a filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different options for how to handle errors and using `decode()` a bit differently, which you can read [more about in the documentation](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/decode.html).

In `decode`, you case specify `errors='strict'`, `errors='ignore'`, or `errors='replace'`. If unspecified, `strict` is the default, and will throw an error when it finds itself in a situation like yours. `ignore` will simply ignore the invalid characters. `replace` replaces the character with a "suitable replacement character."

So, one way this might be implemented could be:

```
import gzip

with gzip.open(logDir + "\\" + fileName, mode="rb") as archive:
    for line in archive:
        decoded_line = line.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore').strip()
        print(decoded_line)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I added your changes, but that just gave me new errors. These errors just don't seem to make sense. This error is:

  File "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Python\ConvertLog.py", line 16, in readZIP
    decoded_line = line('utf-8', errors='ignore').strip()
TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable

Comment: @PrisonFeed It appears you didn't write it correctly. Your comment has `decoded_line = line('utf-8', errors='ignore').strip()`. Note that my answer has `decoded_line = line.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore').strip()`. You forgot to put the `.decode` after `line`.

Comment: Oh wow! I copied/pasted too. *shrug* Thank you. Its working!